# How to highlight android EditText text and display cursor at end?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Highlight `EditText` text and display cursor at end of the text as shown in this image.

[image]

Comment: on what event u wanna highlight text? While typing?

Comment: use a spannable string and set the background. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100228/edittext-change-background-color-of-text-and-only-text-not-the-whole-view

Comment: Thank u Raghunandan.text Highlighting is fine but along with highlight how to display cursor at the end.see attached image

Answer (score 0):

Cn you eplain wat exactly you are luking for,

This helps to highlight text of edittext but cursor position should be manage programmatically:

```
editText.selectAll();
```