# What is a best approach to implemet Youtube/Facebook kind of tag functionality in android application?

Tags: android, tags, logic

In my application i have requirement to implement tag functionality, like we tag particular user in stackoverflow/facebook.

For Example if i press `@a`... on that time i will get list of suggested items for that character from server,and i will show a list of items , selecting any item from list i need to display that on edit text, with some highlighted portion and cross shape on the button.

For example while asking questions on stack overflow site, if i write `ruby-on-rails` and select `ruby-on-rails` from the suggested tag than it will shown as below

[image]

And when i press back press or cross button of that tagged button, entire text should be disappear,

I need to implement same functionality in my application, the only difference is that i will write anchor tag like `@ruby-on-rails` than will get suggestions of keyword from server.

Any guide or suggestion is appriciated

Thanks,

Aamir

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100228/edittext-change-background-color-of-text-and-only-text-not-the-whole-view?

Answer (score 2):

Try this https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout Using this **FlowLayout** you can create **token views** like you want.

Have a look on this SO answer by Romain Guy https://stackoverflow.com/a/4474533/3020568

You can check this links also

1. https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete
2. http://www.kpbird.com/2013/02/android-chips-edittext-token-edittext.html

Comment: Can yu pls tell what is missing now?

Comment: Actually it's adding view dynamically. and i want to add tag functionality inside edit tex box

Comment: i think this blog deals with that. http://www.kpbird.com/2013/02/android-chips-edittext-token-edittext.html

Comment: Yeah, i tried it before two days, it's multi auto complete text view, but it has a limitation, in bewtween two tag, if we write any other text than it's not going to work,so i have to do it with own customization

Comment: @Aamirkhan hey did u complete ?